# my react application can run on VM but not on docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a sample react project and whenever I run

```
..npp install
..npm run
...
Compiled successfully!

You can now view material-kit-pro-react in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://10.0.1.4:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

the server comes up and it works (it used react-script); However, I aimed to dockerize it and used below dockerfile

```
FROM node:12
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /var/tmp/thermo && chown -R root:root /var/tmp/thermo
WORKDIR /var/tmp/thermo
COPY * ./
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "run","start"]
```

I could successfully make image but when I run docker file I see the below logs n the container as it existed the program

```
[root@*****]# docker logs 5edbd29016bd

> material-kit-pro-react@1.9.0 start /var/tmp/thermo
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /var/tmp/thermo/public
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! material-kit-pro-react@1.9.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the material-kit-pro-react@1.9.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-07-30T08_03_34_725Z-debug.log
[root@**********8]#
```

I don't see such error when I run without dockerization on my VM.

Comment: get access into the container and see whether it contains required files (whether it has correct folder structure) - `docker exec -it <container-id> bash`

Comment: did you try the answer which i have written below?

Comment: yes, it is right but I revamped the configs..

Answer (score 0):

In your dockerfile change

COPY * ./

to

COPY . ./

and build it again then run, that'll fix it.